# How to truly remove all references from VS 2008 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project that has a reference to a dll. I removed the reference to version 1 and added a new reference to version 2. The project builds successfully, however when I analyze the project dll after it has been built in Reflector I am seeing that it is holding onto two references to the same dll - version 1 and version 2 are both referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your project file in notepad, can you see both references in there? You may have to scan through a bit of xml to find them... If so, you could manually remove the old one and resave the project in notepad.

Comment: +1 I have often had to do this in every Visual Studio since 6.0.  Sigh.

Comment: Alternatively, you can Unload the project from Visual Studio. Then, and "Edit Project" command becomes available. You can edit the project file as XML, complete with some Intellisense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however after looking at the csproj file i cannot find a reference to the old dll

Answer (score 0):

go to Property pages and remove it easily